# Can we use simple alternating optimization for minimax (saddle point) problems?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Consider a function $f(x,y)$, convex in $x$ and concave in $y$. we are interested in the following optimization problem,
\begin{align}
\min_{x \in D_x} \max_{y \in D_y} f(x,y)
\end{align}
Because of convexity in $x$ and concavity in $y$, we have
\begin{align}
\max_{y \in D_y} \min_{x \in D_x} f(x,y)= \min_{x \in D_x} \max_{y \in D_y} f(x,y)
\end{align}
Question: In which conditions, we can fix $y=y^k$ and minimze $x$ and then fix $x=x^{k}$ and maximize $y$ and converges to global saddle point of the original problem?

If conditions are not known, how can we solve this problem using methods like Augmented Lagrangian in $x$ and some other method in $y$?
EDIT: I searched a lot on the internet, but I didn't find anything completely relevant to what I need. In my problem case, $f(x,y)$ is of the form, 
\begin{align}
f(x,y=(u,Q))=x^T u- \rho x^T Q x\cr
\end{align}
$y=(u,Q)$ is the second argument of the function and the function is linear in $y$.
$D_x$ is the set $x\in [l,u]$ and $D_y$ is a complex set consists of semidefinite constraints. It is very simple to project on the set $D_x$, although the set $D_y$ is more complex but it's not so difficult to project on to.

Comment: A bit of Googling reveals quite a bit of work on the topic. That would be a much better initial resource than this forum.

Comment: I agree with @MichaelGrant. Studying such a problem is an entire research topic on it's own. What is $f$ ? Any structure (for example $f(x, y) = x^TAy$) ? What are the sets $D_x$ and $D_y$ ?  Any structure (for example easy to project onto them) ? Without further information, they is nothing to do.

Comment: @MichaelGrant, Would you suggest some practical algorithms. Not algorithms that keep a bunch of vectors for the inner problem and optimize the outer problem with respect to that.  want to work on the method, but I don't know which way to go?

Comment: I can't, sorry. Google is your best bet here.

Comment: @dohmatob, I edit question to answer your questions. I read a lot on the internet, but didn't find a way what to do. Thank you very much.

Comment: What kind of function is $y \mapsto Q(y)$  ? What's "lifting procedure" ? Please try not to use application-area-specific jargon.

Comment: IF you understand prox operators, you may want to look at http://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~monteiro/publications/tech_reports/saddle_v4.pdf

Comment: @dohmatob, In convex relaxation literature, relaxation $Q=y y^T$ to  $Q  \succcurlyeq y y^T$ is named lifting procedure.

Comment: Thank you for introducing this paper. In paper, it is said that generalized saddle-point problems are in the form: $g(y)+<x, Ay>+h(x)$, but I am confused about the term, $<x, Qx>$( where $Q$ is the first parameter and  $x$ is the second one), is this term representable as the Generalized form?

Comment: @dohmatob, I edit question to do your suggestion. Thank you, now it's better.

Comment: OK, take $\Psi(x, y) = x^Tu - \rho x^T Q x$, $g_1 = i_{D_Y}$, and $g_2 = i_{D_X}$ (I've swapped the roles of $x$ and $y$ to conform to your particular min-max), and then apply algorithm T-BD, noting that $\text{prox}_{g_1} = \text{proj}_{D_Y}$, etc.

Comment: This might help: I have successfully used that primal-dual algorithm in the context of algorithmic game theory http://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.07901v5.pdf

Comment: Thank you for introducing your very good work and also, paper for T-BD. I am currently reading them. I am also thinking and working on the paper, https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjtvqv2h87LAhUmp3IKHdWOCQYQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwebpages.math.luc.edu%2F~rgoebel1%2Fpublications%2FGoebel08JCA.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFeDSPAY22fP33kN2n3vfps6KJ6zw&sig2=AGXPQFx7kuKyBW8k8o4JRg&bvm=bv.117218890,d.bGQ,  about self-dual regularization or something like proximal average.

Comment: I am thinking are these methods applicable to this problem and are this methods prevent the algorithm from cycling?